# Are you affected by your own Blasphemy spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, alignment

Are you (the caster) affected by a [Blasphemy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/blasphemy) spell you cast if you are non-evil?

If you are, if you raise your CL somehow (feats/items), are you affected by 2 or more effects? Can you cast it with a lower CL than your max so as to avoid harmful effects?

Comment: FYI, I'm interested because I'm a Chaotic Neutral cleric of a True Neutral deity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**YES to all**

Blaspheming as a non-evil caster (or an alignment-changed good outsider) is a **Bad Idea**.  Especially with the ubiquitous caster level buffs.  It's a great way to [YASD](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/YetAnotherStupidDeath) in Pathfinder.

Note that (other than 'dead') you do get off slightly better than most creatures, assuming you cast as you last action on a turn; your conditions end on your initiative count of the round they end, so, for example, if you daze yourself you stop being dazed just before your next turn and don't lose it, though you still can't take any more actions before then, still are vulnerable to special attacks requiring dazed targets till then, etc.

You *can* cast at a lower CL with any spell, if you'd like to, and you can choose to do so at the time of casting.  If you have to do so to cast these spells, however, it's probably not a good idea to be casting them at all. The following rule applies:

> You can cast a spell at a lower caster level than normal, but the caster level you choose must be high enough for you to cast the spell in question, and all level-dependent features must be based on the same caster level.